# Vent cap came off, there's no fastener holding it

Tags: vent, roofing, hardware

I did bathroom remodels recently.

Then there was a strong wind a few days ago, and one of the vent caps came off of the roof.

Today I went up on the roof to find out there's no hooks on vent to hold the cap.
[image][image]
The other one has hooks, so I guess that's how it's supposed to be.
[image]

What'd be the best (or cost effective) way to fasten the cap?
I'm thinking of loctite or nails, but would like to have some advice before I mess things up.